# How to convert dictionaries to nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the dictionary as shown below:

```
dict1 = {'K7': ['k07 = v07', ''], 'K2': ['k02 = v02', ''], 'K01': ['k2 = v2', 'k02 = v2', ''], 'K3': ['k1 = v1', ''], 'K02': ['k2 = v2', '']}
```

I am trying to make a nested dictionary as follows:

```
dict1 = [{'K7': {'k07' : 'v07'}}, {'K2': {'k02' : 'v02'}}, {'K01': {'k2' : 'v2','k02' : 'v2'}, {'K3': {'k1' : 'v1'}}, {'K02': {'k2' : 'v2'}}]
```

This is the code that I have tried:

```
 dict2 = []
 for ks,vs in list(dict1.iteritems()):

     vs = filter(None, vs)
     vi1 = [i.split('=', 1)[0] for i in vs]
     vi2 = [i.split('=', 1)[1] for i in vs] 

     for v1, v2 in zip(vi1,vi2):
         dict2.append({ks : {v1 : v2}})
```

But, my output looks as below:

```
  dict2 = [{'K7': {'k07' : 'v07'}}, {'K2': {'k02' : 'v02'}}, {'K01': {'k2' : 'v2'}}, {'K01': {'k02' : 'v2'}}, {'K3': {'k1' : 'v1'}}, {'K02': {'k2' : 'v2'}}]
```

Pleased to hear some suggestions. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict` with a list comprehension:

```
dict1 = {'K7': ['k07 = v07', ''], 'K2': ['k02 = v02', ''], 'K01': ['k2 = v2', 'k02 = v2', ''], 'K3': ['k1 = v1', ''], 'K02': ['k2 = v2', '']}
new_d = [{a:dict(i.split(' = ') for i in b if i)} for a, b in dict1.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'K7': {'k07': 'v07'}}, {'K2': {'k02': 'v02'}}, {'K01': {'k2': 'v2', 'k02': 'v2'}}, {'K3': {'k1': 'v1'}}, {'K02': {'k2': 'v2'}}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I get the value error as follow:ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @ali Are you using the same dictionary as `dict1`? If so, please post your new input. Most likely, your input contains a string element that does not contain `' = '`.

Comment: -Is it possible to make the output into a list? I mean, nested dictionary inside the list

Comment: @ali Sure. Can you post your desired output? Thank you.